# How to update ISODate to two days later

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to convert a SQL query to mongodb query?

Please write a mongodb query - this is my query in SQL:

```
UPDATE user  
SET expireIn = DATEADD(DAY, 2, expireIn) 
WHERE phone = '123434574'
```

I want to add some day to `expireIn` column.

`expireIn` field is `ISODate` and also has a value for the time.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome Mostafa Asadi,
You can do something like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  phone: "123434574"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "expireIn": {
        $dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$expireIn",
          unit: "day",
          amount: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
],{multi:true})
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FIbwPBQ_XJt).

The first `{}` are the `matching` part, which documents do you want to update. The second part is the updating, here inside `[]` as this is a pipeline, using the `$dateAdd` function.

Edit:

with {multi: true} for multiple documents update

Comment: Tnx. Very good. Please write this query withoute condition. I think write multi=true end of query but not working withoute first {}, [.... ], multi=tru}

Comment: Updated according to the comment

Comment: This error returned for all user query:
... ],{"multi" : true})],{"multi" : true})
WriteResult({
  "nMatched" : 0,
  "nUpserted" : 0,
  "nModified" : 0,
  "writeError" : {
    "code" : 5166403,
    "errmsg" : "$dateAdd requires startDate to be convertible to a date"
  }
})

Comment: it seems like one (or more) of your userss has a `expireIn` which is not an `ISODate` or don't have this field at all. You can run db.collection.find({phone: "123434574"}) to see all of them

Comment: Tnx a lot. That been syntax error.

Comment: If it is working for you, please mark the answer as accepted, so it will be easier to others to find it